# How do I compare two objects in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have a list of cluster id's that I'm passing in as a parameter value to a DevOps pipeline. I want to compare this list against the list of cluster id's that I'm retrieving from Azure Databricks workspace. If a cluster id matches, I want to display a Found message. However, the if statement to compare is resulting into the below error. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks in advance for your help.

- Error message:   if (040-192905 -eq $clusterID)
  |                    ~
  | You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator

````
parameters:

- name: cluster_ids
  type: object
  default: ['040-192905','020-193152','009-193435']

      - ${{ each param_cluster_id in parameters.cluster_ids }}:
        - task: AzurePowerShell@5
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '$(xxxxxx)'
            ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
            Inline: |
               $wsclusters = Get-DatabricksClusters -BearerToken $(bearer_token) -Region $(region)
              # Iterate through these clusters
              foreach($wscluster in $wsclusters)
              { 
                $clusterName = $wscluster.cluster_name
                $clusterID = $wscluster.cluster_id
                 if (${{param_cluster_id}} -eq $wsclusterID)
                {
                  Write-Host "Parameter Cluster ID matches Workspace Cluster ID"
                }
              }
            azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion' ```
````

Comment: Just a guess, but try double-quoting the template expression - i.e. ```if ("${{param_cluster_id}}" -eq $wsclusterID)``` - I'm presuming the ```${{ }}``` gets pre-processed before the powershell script is executed, so it's resolving to ```if( 040-192905 -eq $wsclusterID)```, but ```040-192905``` is evaluated as a math expression (equals ```-192865```) rather than the string ```"040-192905"```. Might not be the root issue, but you'll probably bump into this anyway...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However I have noticed that the problem is with the  - ${{ each param_cluster_id in parameters.cluster_ids }}: Looks like the parameter values are not getting passed to the Powershell task. Their values are showing up as empty. Any help please?

Comment: Thanks, the above response was useful and fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Changes made as per response from mclayton and it worked. Thanks.
("${{param_cluster_id}}" -eq $wsclusterID)